# ASP.NET Error creating Controller Dynamically

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Please help, I want to try to create a controller but in a dynamic way, but this appears when I press "Add":

[image: screenshot result]

Here is what I type in the code generator:

[image: screenshot code generator]

I don't understand how come I got these errors, all I just do is just follow this lecture video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfEjDD8mWYg&t=1229s

Comment: The linked video is for ASP.NET **Core** - are you using ASP.NET **Core**, too?  If so - please say so in your question and use the appropriate `asp.net-core` tag !

Comment: The error does explain what your issue is.
You try to add your controller, while your CURRENT code dosent compile and has errors.
If you fix those, compile your program and then try to add it, no error would come out.

Comment: I would suggest you to report this as an issue with Visual Studio. You can use the feedback icon in the upper right for this (directly next to the quick launch search adn the yellow flag that is likely telling you about some updates).

Comment: reinstall the visual studio I think. It shouldn't be a code-related issue but the client issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is outside of the class. You need to put this code inside the class brackets:

```
public class Employee 
{
     public Employee() //This is the constructor of the class
     {
     } 

     public int id { get; set; } //This is a property
     //All of the other properties...
}
```

Comment: I actually still got error after correcting the code, the code mention like something wrong with MySQL version, and now when I try again it only mention the db context already exist